# pivot_*() function in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I am trying to create a `tibble` that contain `property_id` and the facilities columns with the true or false values in them. I have tried the following but not able to proceed further.

```
properties %>% 
  select(property_id, facilities) %>% 
  separate(facilities, into = paste0("f", 1:9), sep = ",")
```

```
> dput(head(properties))
structure(list(property_id = c(2668, 4656, 4563, 4088, 2188, 
4171), destination = c("Brisbane", "Brisbane", "Brisbane", "Brisbane", 
"Brisbane", "Brisbane"), property_type = c("Hotel", "Hotel", 
"Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment"), nr_rooms = c(32, 
39, 9, 9, 4, 5), facilities = c("airport shuttle,free wifi,garden,breakfast,pool,on-site restaurant", 
"on-site restaurant,pool,airport shuttle,breakfast,bbq,free wifi,spa", 
"laundry", "kitchen,laundry,free wifi", "parking,kitchen,bbq,free wifi,game console", 
"kitchen,pool,laundry,parking,free wifi,garden")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We split the 'facilities' column by `,`, use `mtabulate` from `qdapTools` to get the count of each of unique elements in the `list`, convert to logical matrix (`> 0`) and `cbind` the 'property_id' column

```
library(qdapTools)
cbind(properties['property_id'], mtabulate(strsplit(properties$facilities, ",")) > 0)
```

-output

```
property_id airport shuttle   bbq breakfast free wifi game console garden kitchen laundry on-site restaurant parking  pool   spa
1        2668            TRUE FALSE      TRUE      TRUE        FALSE   TRUE   FALSE   FALSE               TRUE   FALSE  TRUE FALSE
2        4656            TRUE  TRUE      TRUE      TRUE        FALSE  FALSE   FALSE   FALSE               TRUE   FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
3        4563           FALSE FALSE     FALSE     FALSE        FALSE  FALSE   FALSE    TRUE              FALSE   FALSE FALSE FALSE
4        4088           FALSE FALSE     FALSE      TRUE        FALSE  FALSE    TRUE    TRUE              FALSE   FALSE FALSE FALSE
5        2188           FALSE  TRUE     FALSE      TRUE         TRUE  FALSE    TRUE   FALSE              FALSE    TRUE FALSE FALSE
6        4171           FALSE FALSE     FALSE      TRUE        FALSE   TRUE    TRUE    TRUE              FALSE    TRUE  TRUE FALSE
>
```

Comment: I have edited the post as per request, I am able to separate it but not sure how to use the pivot_*() for it.

Comment: Is it possible to obtain only the properties_id column and the comma-separated values?

Answer (score 3):

In `tidyr` we may use `separate_rows` and `pivot_wider`

```r
properties <- structure(list(property_id = c(2668, 4656, 4563, 4088, 2188, 
                               4171), destination = c("Brisbane", "Brisbane", "Brisbane", "Brisbane", 
                                                      "Brisbane", "Brisbane"), property_type = c("Hotel", "Hotel", 
                                                                                                 "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment", "Apartment"), nr_rooms = c(32, 
                                                                                                                                                                   39, 9, 9, 4, 5), facilities = c("airport shuttle,free wifi,garden,breakfast,pool,on-site restaurant", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   "on-site restaurant,pool,airport shuttle,breakfast,bbq,free wifi,spa", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   "laundry", "kitchen,laundry,free wifi", "parking,kitchen,bbq,free wifi,game console", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                   "kitchen,pool,laundry,parking,free wifi,garden")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
properties %>% separate_rows(facilities, sep = ',') %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(property_id, destination, property_type), names_from = facilities, values_from = nr_rooms,
              values_fn = function(x) is.numeric(x), values_fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 15
#>   property_id destination property_type `airport shuttle` `free wifi` garden
#>         <dbl> <chr>       <chr>         <lgl>             <lgl>       <lgl> 
#> 1        2668 Brisbane    Hotel         TRUE              TRUE        TRUE  
#> 2        4656 Brisbane    Hotel         TRUE              TRUE        FALSE 
#> 3        4563 Brisbane    Apartment     FALSE             FALSE       FALSE 
#> 4        4088 Brisbane    Apartment     FALSE             TRUE        FALSE 
#> 5        2188 Brisbane    Apartment     FALSE             TRUE        FALSE 
#> 6        4171 Brisbane    Apartment     FALSE             TRUE        TRUE  
#> # ... with 9 more variables: breakfast <lgl>, pool <lgl>,
#> #   on-site restaurant <lgl>, bbq <lgl>, spa <lgl>, laundry <lgl>,
#> #   kitchen <lgl>, parking <lgl>, game console <lgl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**Needless to say, unwanted columns may be removed from `id_cols` argument of `pivot_wider`**